# SET selected in the select tag

Tags: php, mysql

```
<select class="form-control" name="Church" id="Church">
  <option>Church List</option>
    <?php 
         $select_church = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblchurchs");
         while($get_detail = mysql_fetch_array($select_church)){
          echo'<option value="'.$get_detail['AChurchID'].'">'.$get_detail['ChurchName']." - ".$get_detail['Address'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

This is Edit.php

This is the result of that code
[image]
but i want is. after getting the data from the database. it will automatically selected the value of the option base on the database data.

Comment: Which option do you want selected? What indicator is returned for that from the database?

Comment: @Kenneth Suaverdez please look at below i have posted one ans for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the selected item in a drop down box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336353/how-do-i-set-the-selected-item-in-a-drop-down-box)

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the query result returned from `tblchurchs` contains a field `Selected` which is either set to `1` or `0`. If it is set to 1 then you have to select that option in your drop-down list, and if it is set to 0, it is not selected.

```
<select class="form-control" name="Church" id="Church">
  <option>Church List</option>
    <?php 
         $select_church = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblchurchs");
         while($get_detail = mysql_fetch_array($select_church)){
          echo'<option value="'.$get_detail['AChurchID'].'"';
          if($get_detail['Selected'] == 1)
            {
                echo ' selected="selected"';
            }
          echo '>'.$get_detail['ChurchName']." - ".$get_detail['Address'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

to getting selected for selected option. 
first you have to save the selected data getting from database to a variable and then using an if loop you can do this.

```
<?php 
$AChurchID=1; // this is your already selected value that is in db .
?>
<select class="form-control" name="Church" id="Church">
  <option>Church List</option>
    <?php 
         $select_church = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblchurchs");
         while($get_detail = mysql_fetch_array($select_church)){
            $sel="";
            if($AChurchID==$get_detail['AChurchID']){
            $sel="selected";
        }
          echo'<option value="'.$get_detail['AChurchID'].'" '.$sel.'>'.$get_detail['ChurchName']." - ".$get_detail['Address'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
```

This will work in your case. This is works fine in ma case. Please have a try.