# Selected item gets changed in dropdown list

Tags: php, html

When I select any other item apart from the first item in the dropdown list it loads the corresponding values and then again selects the first item from the list and does not retain the item I selected.

[image]

In the above image I had selected the USA from the dropdown list, it displayed the corresponding names and then again India (first item in the list) was seen in the list.
What I want is that the name USA (or whichever name I select) should be seen in the list.
I am new to HTML kindly advise some changes in below code to achieve above functionality.
Do we have any attribute which will help in to achieve the above goal

```
<html>
<body>

<form action = "StateNames.php" method = "post">

    Select a Country Name 
    <select name = "n1">
      <option value="india">India</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
      <option value="aus">Australia</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" name = "Submit">  

</form>

</body>
</html> 

<?php

if(isset($_POST['n1']))
{
    $name = $_POST['n1'];

    $India = array("Maharashta", "Goa", "Himachal Pradesh", "Jammu and 
Kashmir", "Uttaakhand");
    $USA = array("New York", "California", "Washington", "Texas", "Utah");
    $Australia = array("New South Wales", "Victoria", "Queensland", 
"Tasmania");

    switch($name)
    {
        case "india":
            foreach($India as $i)
                echo $i ."<br/>";
                break;

        case "usa":
            foreach($USA as $u)
                echo $u ."<br/>";
                break;

        case "aus":
            foreach($Australia as $a)
                echo "$a <br/>";
                break;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: you need to use the selected attribute for the option you have selected... As the page refreshes, you lose your selection.

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336353/how-do-i-set-the-selected-item-in-a-drop-down-box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the selected item in a drop down box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336353/how-do-i-set-the-selected-item-in-a-drop-down-box)

Comment: I saw the above link but was unable to implement the code.

It would be helpful if you could make some necessary changes in the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
<body>

<form action = "StateNames.php" method = "post">

    Select a Country Name 
    <select name = "n1">
    <?php if(isset($_POST['n1'])) { ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $_POST['n1']; ?>" selected><?php echo $_POST['n1']; ?></option>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <option value="">Choose a option</option>
    <?php } ?>
      <option value="india">India</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
      <option value="aus">Australia</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" name = "Submit">  

</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['n1']))
{
    $name = $_POST['n1'];

    $India = array("Maharashta", "Goa", "Himachal Pradesh", "Jammu and 
Kashmir", "Uttaakhand");
    $USA = array("New York", "California", "Washington", "Texas", "Utah");
    $Australia = array("New South Wales", "Victoria", "Queensland", 
"Tasmania");

    switch($name)
    {
        case "india":
            foreach($India as $i)
                echo $i ."<br/>";
                break;

        case "usa":
            foreach($USA as $u)
                echo $u ."<br/>";
                break;

        case "aus":
            foreach($Australia as $a)
                echo "$a <br/>";
                break;
    }
    }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I have rearranged your code and it should be something like that.

So the PHP in the `select` block, checks is the `$_POST['n1']` has a value, if so it prints the first `options` tag with the value of `$_POST['n1']` and mark it as selected. Otherwise, it prints the second `options` tag instead.

> Here is a much more advance version that solve those problems you've mentioned

```html
<?php

// This creates a multidimestional array of countries
// Syntax Key => Value
// Country => States
$countries = array(
    "India" => array("Maharashta", "Goa", "Himachal Pradesh", "Jammu and Kashmir", "Uttaakhand"),
    "USA" => array("New York", "California", "Washington", "Texas", "Utah"),
    "Australia" => array("New South Wales", "Victoria", "Queensland", "Tasmania")
);
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action = "StateNames.php" method = "post">
            Select a Country Name 
            <select name = "n1">

            <!-- If a value already selected, show that -->
                <?php if (isset($_POST['n1'])) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $_POST['n1']; ?>" selected><?php echo $_POST['n1']; ?></option>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <option value="" selected>Choose a option</option>
                <?php } ?>

                <!-- Foreach loop that map Key as $country and Value as $states  -->
                <?php foreach($countries as $country => $states) { ?>

                <!-- If n1 already set -->
                    <?php if (isset($_POST['n1'])) {?>

                    <!-- Skip that option to avoind duplication on the list. In this case $country is not equal to n1, add as option -->
                        <?php if ($_POST['n1'] != $country) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $country; ?>"><?php echo $country; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <!-- If n1 not set print all options -->
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $country; ?>"><?php echo $country; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" name = "Submit">
        </form>
        <?php
if(isset($_POST['n1']))
{
    $name = $_POST['n1'];

    // Here is the n1 is set we loop through array and print all the states out for that selected country
    foreach($countries as $country => $states) {
        if ($name == $country) {
            foreach($states as $state) {
              echo $state ."<br/>";  
            }
        }
    }
}
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Live example, only good for 48H](http://main.xfiddle.com/09bcc3c8/states.php)

Comment: Tried the above code but it is still not retaining the state.

Comment: Does it refresh the page when you click a result?

Comment: Here is a live test, only good for 48H. http://main.xfiddle.com/09bcc3c8/StateNames.php

Comment: When I click on search it refreshes the page and gives me the output but the option which I had selected is not retained.

Also it would be helpful if you could advise why did we write the php code in select tag and why the values being echoed inside php in select tag were not shown in the output.

Comment: Have you tried the link above? and I've added little explanation

Comment: Yes checked it just now, it changes the name in the dropdownlist to the value attribute of the option tag. I changed the value attribute to the actual name i.e.; usa to USA but observed below 2 issues. 1. An extra element gets added to the dropdown list. 2. After changing the value attribute to the actual name i.e.; usa to USA etc it worked only for India for other selections their value was being added to the list but the names of the city was not being displayed. Kindly help with the above issues. Thank you

Comment: I have updated the code have a look if this what you looking for

Comment: Yes, Thank You for the explanation.