# Why my select is not change after i call this.form.submit()?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have a problem when i want to select dropdown after that the value in option not change and back to normal again. i want to know how to make when i choose an option in dropdown select the value keep on i choose not back to normal ? sorry for my bad english.. look at example below

```
    $out .= '<form method="POST" >';
    $out .= '   <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed"><tbody>';
    $out .- '       <tr>';
    $out .= '           <td class="info" width="5%"><b>Race</b></td>';
    $out .= '           <td>';
    $out .= '               <select class="form-control" name="race_select" onchange="this.form.submit();">';
    $out .= '                   <option value selected>All Races</option>';
    $out .= '                   <option>Accretia</option>';
    $out .= '                   <option>Bellato</option>';
    $out .= '                   <option>Cora</option>';
    $out .= '               </select>';
    $out .= '           </td>';
    $out .= '       </tr>';
    $out .= '   </tbody></table>';
    $out .= '</form>';
    $out .= '<br>';
```

look i have select option when i choose for e.g Accretia. when it render again the value in option still All races, i want to when people choose some option, the value in option keep that people choose not back to All races again.

look at this image
[image]

when i choose bellato the option not change to bellato but still All Races

Comment: because of `value selected`

Comment: because you have `this.form.submit()` in your select this gets submitted and the default value gets loaded again.

Comment: so how to fix it? when i choose Bellato or something the option change to Bellato not All Races ?

Comment: has you are submitting form using post then get  `$_POST['race_select']` value and set that in your select as selected option.Here is an  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1336376/10606400)

Comment: what do you mean? its different problem, i jsut want to display what i select. because i want to click All races if i want to display all race. but if i want to select just acretia or something on the option , the view will be that i choose. that success i did. but the option still not change to its value, always All Races