# problem in getting values from select options

Tags: php, html

below is the code which i have problem and the problem is how can i get values if value="php echo $someting;" instead of value="someting"

like how i put value when i use condition if($_POST['city']=='')
how can i put echo value in if statement

anyone got my point then please answer.

```
<select class="js-example-placeholder-single js-states form-control" id="city" name="city" 
title="Select City" data-hide-disabled="true" data-live-search="true">
<optgroup label="Location">

<option value="">No Selection</option>
<?php

$cities = $db->get ("cities");
foreach ($cities as $city){ 

?>
<option value="<?php echo $city['city_name']; ?>" <?php if($city['city_name'] == 
$selected_city) echo "selected"; ?> >
                       
<?php echo $city['city_name']; ?>

</option>

<?php } ?>


</optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: `$selected_city = isset($_POST['city) ? $_POST['city'] : false;` should make this work (obvs above the foreach loop)

Comment: Is this in a .php or .html file (sorry, just to check)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the selected item in a drop down box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336353/how-do-i-set-the-selected-item-in-a-drop-down-box)

Comment: if i get value by variable like   if($_POST['city']==$city['city_name]){ }  it gives an error undefined variable...what is the solution??

Answer (score 0):

Just add `empty($_POST['city']) ? 'selected' : ''` on empty option:

```php-template
<?php
$selected_city = $_POST['city'] ?? null;
?>

<select class="js-example-placeholder-single js-states form-control" id="city" name="city" title="Select City" data-hide-disabled="true" data-live-search="true">
    <optgroup label="Location">

        <option value="" <?= empty($selected_city) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>No Selection</option>
        <?php
        $cities = $db->get("cities");
        foreach ($cities as $city):
        ?>
        <option value="<?= $city['city_name']; ?>" <?= $city['city_name'] == $selected_city ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
            <?= $city['city_name']; ?>
        </option>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: dear i want to compare two select option values like if($_POST['city']=='something'){ }elseif($_POST['city']=='something'){}  but the problem is value is not in text its in php as you see in the code.if you know then plz answr how i put if($_POST['city']== $city[city_name]

Comment: @Sohail I am not dear, I am cat. Please explain exactly what input you have and what output you want, because now your code `if($_POST['city']=='something'){}` is valid

Comment: dear i want to compare two select option values like if($_POST['city']=='something'){ }elseif($_POST['city']=='something'){}  but the problem is value is not in text its in php as you see in the code.if you know then plz answr how i put if($_POST['city']== $city[city_name]

Comment: @Sohail It's really not clear for me what you want. `if($_POST['city']== $city[city_name]` will work fine. Maybe you want `if ($_POST['city'] == 'something' || $_POST['city'] == 'something_else')`?

Comment: dear you are right if($_POST['city']==$city['city_name']){} works fine but in my scenario i am using value to get results of the value on other page...and there it gives an error undefined variable $city